# Adding a new default tier on API Manager

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I'm using API Manager 2.2.0

By default WSO2 API Manager comes with some Subscription Throttling Policies, such as Gold, Silver, and Bronze. I want to add a new one called Diamond.

I added this new tier using the Admin webpage (e.g. https://localhost:9443/admin) on all the existing tenants.

What I want to to now is to make this Diamond tier be generated by default when new tenants are created.

I edited the file `default-tiers.xml` adding the following code:

```
<wsp:Policy>
    <throttle:ID throttle:type="ROLE">Diamond</throttle:ID>
    <wsp:Policy>
        <throttle:Control>
            <wsp:Policy>
                <throttle:MaximumCount>2000</throttle:MaximumCount>
                <throttle:UnitTime>1000</throttle:UnitTime>
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <throttle:Attributes>
                        <throttle:x-wso2-BillingPlan>FREE</throttle:x-wso2-BillingPlan>
                        <throttle:x-wso2-StopOnQuotaReach>true</throttle:x-wso2-StopOnQuotaReach>
                    </throttle:Attributes>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </wsp:Policy>
        </throttle:Control>
    </wsp:Policy>
</wsp:Policy>
```

When I create a new tenant and access the Admin webpage the tier isn't there. If I browse the resources on Carbon for that tenant I can see the file `tiers.xml` has the code above.

Since news tenants don't have it when I subscribe to an API using this Diamond tier it always returns 403 to me. If I use the other ones (e.g. Gold) everything work as expected.

How can I add a new tier to the list of default ones?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Tenants are isolated entities there is no OOTB way to achieve this. However, you can use a `TenantMgtListener` (implement `onTenantCreate`) [1] and call subscription add API[2].

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon4411/TenantMgtListener
[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/apidocs/admin/#!/operations#SubscriptionPolicyCollection#throttlingPoliciesSubscriptionPost

p.s. `default-tiers.xml` nor `tiers.xml` is used in the new throttling implementation.